# Can DbPropertyValues.SetValues be used in reverse to populate a DTO from an entity's current values?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Can the Entity Framework method [DbPropertyValues.SetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679336%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) be used in reverse to set the values of an object, namely a view model or Data Transfer Object, based on the current values of properties within an entity?

This is one example of how I am using SetValues together with DTOs to update only the properties that I specify in the class definition for the DTO.

```
public Address UpdateAddress(Address address)
{
    using (var context = new OrdersContext())
    {
        var targetAddress = context.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressID == address.AddressID && a.User.UserName.ToLower() == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToLower());

        if (targetAddress == null) return null; // Address not found or user doesn't own this address.

        context.Entry(targetAddress).CurrentValues.SetValues(address);
        context.SaveChanges();

        return new Address
        {
            AddressID = targetAddress.AddressID,
            AddressLine1 = targetAddress.AddressLine1,
            AddressLine2 = targetAddress.AddressLine2,
            City = targetAddress.City,
            State = targetAddress.State,
            ZipCode = targetAddress.ZipCode
        };
    }
}

public class Address
{
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    // public string UserID { get; set; } // UserID is excluded from the view model so that it cannot be updated.
}
```

As the documention on SetValues indicates

> The given object can be of any type. Any property on the object with a
>   name that matches a property name in the dictionary and can be read,
>   will be read. Other properties will be ignored. This allows, copying
>   of properties from simple Data Transfer Objects (DTOs).

Can SetValues be used in reverse to set the values of the DTO from the entity, so that the values don't have to be set manually one by one? Or is there another method that works like SetValues but in reverse?

There's another [DbPropertyValues method called ToObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbpropertyvalues.toobject%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), but it doesn't work with DTOs.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
public Address UpdateAddress(Address address)
{
    using (var context = new OrdersContext())
    {
        var targetAddress = context.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressID == address.AddressID && a.User.UserName.ToLower() == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToLower());

        if (targetAddress == null) return null; // Address not found or user doesn't own this address.

        context.Entry(targetAddress).CurrentValues.SetValues(address);
        context.SaveChanges();

        return context.Entry(targetAddress).ToObject(new Address());
    }
}
```

Thanks!